Differentiable of Moreau-Yosida
i read the next paper:
"practical aspects of the Moreau-Yosida regulrization I: theoretical properties
and the introduction" and in the first part it claims that for a given function f and its Moreau-Yosida, the Moreau-Yosida is twice differentiable iff f is twice differentiable .
and i was wondering about the case where f(x) = abs(x) this is not differentiable function at x=0 but it's Moreau-Yosida is twice differentiable. do i miss something?
Thanks!

This does not seem true without any qualifying conditions. Can you point to the specific statement in the paper?
